# Reloading UITableView after adding a new entity from core data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

Currently having problems with reloading the UITableView in my app when adding an entity via a UINavigation add button which triggers the addHero method in the view controllers implementation file. Adding and deleting entities works perfectly well from the core data perspective as when the app is exited and relaunched all the entities appear correctly represented in the tableview. It also works fine when the view reloads when the tab bar selection is made. I have tried reloading the table view but I am not sure where I need to make this method call in the sequence.

```
#pragma mark- NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate Methods

-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController   *)controller
{
[self.heroTableView beginUpdates];
}


-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
[_heroTableView reloadData];
[self.heroTableView endUpdates];

}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller  didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
switch (type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.heroTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet  indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.heroTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet  indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
switch (type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.heroTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.heroTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        break;
}

}

#pragma mark- UIAlertViewDelegateMethods

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
exit(-1);
}


- (IBAction)addHero:(id)sender {

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext =    [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest]entity];
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSError *error =nil;
BOOL sucess =[managedObjectContext save:&error];

if (!sucess) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView  alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error saving entity", @"Error Saving entity") message:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Error was: %@, quitting.", @"Error was: %@,quitting." )] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Aw Nuts", @"Aw Nuts") otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show]
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have finally figured this one out. I had forgotten to set the fetched results controller's delegate to be the tableviewcontroller. However I initially did this in the viewDidLoad method which caused problems .The best solution was to set the fetchedResultscontoller's delegate at the point of instantiation in the getter method.

```
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:sectionKey cacheName:@"Hero"];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate=self;
return _fetchedResultsController;
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines are in conflict:

```
[_heroTableView reloadData];
[self.heroTableView endUpdates];
```

You either update your table between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`, or you renounce animation and just call `reloadData`. The above has unpredictable results.

If your delegate works correctly, it should insert the row where necessary and you should **not** call `reloadData`. From the looks of it you are using the boilerplate `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` so it should work as expected.